# C# bitblt bitmap render to control

Tags: c#, bitmap, rendering, gdi+

I work on a small real-time project where a fast bitmap rendering technique is  quite necessary. I need to display many(hundreds) small blocks in a picturebox per second,i found the `bitblt` example from the [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/BitBlt.html) website.

I use a while loop(right now it's infinite ),to retrieve a particular bitmap,and then calling the `Invalidate()` method to trigger the `Paint` event.

This is my code:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr pTarget = e.Graphics.GetHdc();
        IntPtr pSource = CreateCompatibleDC(pTarget);
        IntPtr pOrig = SelectObject(pSource, bmp.GetHbitmap());
        BitBlt(pTarget, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, pSource, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
        DeleteObject(pOrig);
        DeleteDC(pSource);
        e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(pTarget);
    }
    private void Display()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            frame = desktopDuplicator.GetLatestFrame();
            if (frame != null)
            {
                bmp = frame.DesktopImage;//retrieve image.
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.Invalidate()));//trigger the repaint event
            }

        }
    }
```

It works fine for few seconds,then i'm getting an **`System.ArgumentException`** on this line:

```
BitBlt(pTarget, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, pSource, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here? i keep releasing the used resources(in the paint event)...why i'm getting this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the value of `ParamName` in the exception? This should give you a hint what object you have a problem with: `pTarget`, `bmp`, `pSource`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here? i keep releasing the used resources(in the paint event)...why i'm getting this error?

Actually you are **not** releasing all the used resources, specifically the bitmap handle returned by the `bmp.GetHbitmap()` call. The correct sequence is to select back the original default bitmap handle into device context and then delete your bitmap handle, as explained in the `SelectObject` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162957(v=vs.85).aspx):

> This function returns the previously selected object of the specified type. An application **should always replace a new object with the original, default object after it has finished drawing with the new object**.

```
IntPtr targetDC = e.Graphics.GetHdc();
IntPtr sourceDC = CreateCompatibleDC(targetDC);
IntPtr sourceBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();
IntPtr originalBitmap = SelectObject(sourceDC, sourceBitmap);
BitBlt(targetDC, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, sourceDC, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(sourceDC, originalBitmap);
DeleteObject(sourceBitmap);
DeleteDC(sourceDC);
e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(targetDC);
```

Comment: i'm still getting the same error after few seconds of running.. haha @Ivan Stoev

Comment: Then you have other issues as well. For instance, what is `desktopDuplicator.GetLatestFrame();` (you are assigning it to variable `frame` w/o disposing the previous value. What is `frame.DesktopImage` and again you are assigning it to `bmp` variable w/o disposing the previous value. Also `bmp` variable is not protected between threads. So, what I wrote in the answer still applies, but you need to provide more info (code) for the other parts. Providing some simple `mcve` like the one I did for your previous question that replicates the issue would help resolving it.

Comment: alright...but i must to say the gdi+ methods such as  `DrawImage()` works way faster...

Comment: Well, I understand the disappointment, but you are comparing apples and oranges. The Gdi+ version was drawing small rectangles while this draws the whole screen. I think the problem is due to many transitions - Lock/InlockBits, GetHBitmap / DeleteObject. Also working with Gdi is hard, especially applying scaling. If instead of bitmap objects you have this Gdi bitmap handle all the time, and update somehow portions of it, and also draw only the invalidated parts, then I think Gdi would be faster. But simply replacing DrawImage with something like this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for the [`Bitmap.GetHbitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

> You are responsible for calling the GDI DeleteObject method to free the memory used by the GDI bitmap object.

You don't currently appear to be calling that, which will lead to a leak. You should call `DeleteObject` once you're done with the resource, so maybe something like:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr pTarget = e.Graphics.GetHdc();
    IntPtr pSource = CreateCompatibleDC(pTarget);
    IntPtr pOrig = SelectObject(pSource, bmp.GetHbitmap());
    BitBlt(pTarget, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, pSource, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
    DeleteObject(pOrig);
    DeleteDC(pSource);
    e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(pTarget);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late response.. i guess your'e right but now i'm going 'System.ArgumentException` after few seconds of running throwing in the `bitblt` call  .
`BitBlt(pTarget, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, pSource, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);` @Rowland Shaw